# Cannot Remove GPL-3.0 with Yocto

Tags: linux, yocto, open-source

I am using Yocto Kirkstone to build an image for a custom Embedded Linux device. I want to prevent building with any (L)GPL-3.0 code. I have added meta-gplv2 to my bblayers.conf file.

I have added this to my local.conf file:

```
INCOMPATIBLE_LICENSE = "AGPL-3.0-only AGPL-3.0-or-later GPL-3.0-only GPL-3.0-or-later LGPL-3.0-only"
```

I also inherit the 'license' class in my image file.

I purposefully added 'ufw' ( GPL3.0 ) to my image file to test Yocto's exclusion mechanism.

However, after a clean build, my image still contains ufw, and the tmp/deploy/licenses directory shows several GPL-3.0 licenses for packages.

```
tmp/deploy/licenses$ grep -R -i gpl-3 * | grep -v native 
autoconf-archive/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-with-autoconf-exception
binutils/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-only
binutils-cross-aarch64/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-only
bzip2/recipeinfo:LICENSE: bzip2-1.0.6 & GPL-3.0-or-later & Apache-2.0 & MS-PL & BSD-3-Clause & Zlib
cairo/recipeinfo:LICENSE: (MPL-1.1 | LGPL-2.1-only) & GPL-3.0-or-later
elfutils/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-2.0-only & GPL-2.0-or-later & LGPL-3.0-or-later & GPL-3.0-or-later
gawk/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-only
gcc/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-with-GCC-exception & GPL-3.0-only
gcc-cross-aarch64/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-with-GCC-exception & GPL-3.0-only
gcc-runtime/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-with-GCC-exception
gdbm/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-only
gmp/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-2.0-or-later | LGPL-3.0-or-later
gnutls/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-or-later & LGPL-2.1-or-later
grep/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-only
libassuan/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-or-later & LGPL-2.1-or-later
libgcc/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-with-GCC-exception & GPL-3.0-only
libgcc-initial/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-with-GCC-exception
libgcrypt/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-2.0-or-later & LGPL-2.1-or-later & GPL-3.0-or-later
libidn2/recipeinfo:LICENSE: (GPL-2.0-or-later | LGPL-3.0-only) & GPL-3.0-or-later & Unicode-DFS-2016
libmpc/recipeinfo:LICENSE: LGPL-3.0-only
libtasn1/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-or-later & LGPL-2.1-or-later
libunistring/recipeinfo:LICENSE: LGPL-3.0-or-later | GPL-2.0-or-later
linux-firmware/generic_WHENCE:Licence: GPLv2 or later. See GPL-2 and GPL-3 for details.
linux-firmware/generic_WHENCE:Licence: GPLv2 or later. See GPL-2 and GPL-3 for details.
linux-firmware/generic_WHENCE:Licence: GPLv3. See GPL-3 for details.
linux-firmware/generic_WHENCE:Licence: GPLv2 or later. See GPL-2 and GPL-3 for details.
linux-firmware/generic_WHENCE:Licence: GPLv2 or later. See GPL-2 and GPL-3 for details.
m4/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-only
make/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-only
mpfr/recipeinfo:LICENSE: LGPL-3.0-or-later
nettle/recipeinfo:LICENSE: LGPL-3.0-or-later | GPL-2.0-or-later
networkd-dispatcher/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-only
tar/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-only
ufw/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-3.0-only
usbutils/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-2.0-or-later & (GPL-2.0-only | GPL-3.0-only)
usbutils/lsusb.py.in:# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only OR GPL-3.0-only
util-linux/README.licensing:   * GPL-3.0-or-later   - GNU General Public License version 3, or any later version
util-linux-libuuid/README.licensing:   * GPL-3.0-or-later   - GNU General Public License version 3, or any later version
xz/recipeinfo:LICENSE: GPL-2.0-or-later & GPL-3.0-with-autoconf-exception & LGPL-2.1-or-later & PD
```

It did complain about some LGPL3.0 packages, which I had to remove.

So why is it seemingly allowing GPL3.0 when I specified to remove it? Thanks.

Edit: Neither PARSE_ALL_RECIPES or SOURCE_MIRROR_FETCH are set in my image file.

```
developer@docker-desktop:~/nxp-bsp/build-iot-gate-imx8plus$ bitbake -e my-core-image | grep -i PARSE_ALL_RECIPES
    if need_machine and not d.getVar('PARSE_ALL_RECIPES', False):
    source_mirror_fetch = d.getVar('SOURCE_MIRROR_FETCH', False) or d.getVar('PARSE_ALL_RECIPES', False)
developer@docker-desktop:~/nxp-bsp/build-iot-gate-imx8plus$ bitbake -e my-core-image | grep -i SOURCE_MIRROR_FETCH
# $SOURCE_MIRROR_FETCH
    source_mirror_fetch = d.getVar('SOURCE_MIRROR_FETCH', False) or d.getVar('PARSE_ALL_RECIPES', False)
    if not source_mirror_fetch:
        source_mirror_fetch = d.getVar('SOURCE_MIRROR_FETCH', False)
        if not source_mirror_fetch:
```

Comment: Do you have `license` added to the `INHERIT_DISTRO` variable (or do you inherit the license class on any other way)?

Comment: I did inherit license in my image file - but it still includes the GPL3 packages.

Comment: By any chance, do you happen to have the `PARSE_ALL_RECIPES` or `SOURCE_MIRROR_FETCH` variables set somewhere? These can prevent license verification.

Comment: I just checked with bitbake -e and I do not see those variable set.

Comment: Well, if no one has any ideas, you can always go the oldschool debug-with-print way. You could sprinkle [base.bbclass](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/classes/base.bbclass?h=kirkstone#n593) with delicate `if ("ufw" in pkg) bb.warn("very reasonable debug msg")` lines around line 600-ish...